# How can I get my program to be run continuous, while going back to a child process?

Tags: c, linux, fork, exec, parent-child

As I am using the fork() function, I have my child process use the execlp() function. Because It doesn't work with a continuous while-loop. (I'm using a Linux environment)

So the child should be forked which is responsible for the exec() call, and the parent should be responsible for the loop and the input logic.

---

Here is my code:

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){


    char *cmd[] = {"pwd", "ls", "date", "ps", "top"};
    int i;
    printf("0=pwd, 1=ls, 2=date, 3=ps, 4=top:\n");
    printf("Please print your input: ");
    scanf("%d", &i);


    int The_fork = fork();  

    if(The_fork == 0){

        execlp(cmd[i], cmd[i], NULL);
        printf("command no found\n");
 
    }else{

        wait(0);

        while(1){

            int status;
            waitpid(The_fork, &status, 0);


            printf("\n");
            char *cmd[] = {"pwd", "ls", "date", "ps", "top"};
            int i;
            printf("0=pwd, 1=ls, 2=date, 3=ps, 4=top:\n");
            printf("Please print your input: ");
            scanf("%d", &i);
            //execlp(cmd[i], cmd[i], NULL);
       
        }

        return 1;
    }



return 0;
}
```

---

Here is my output:

[image]

(The parent is printing continuously, but I can't figure out how to get the child to execute continuously after its first print.)

Comment: It's not clear what you expect the child to do. You have shown the actual result but what is the exact expected result?

Comment: *while going back to a child class*. It is difficult to understand this key part of your question. There are no classes in C and what does "going back" mean exactly?

Comment: I modified your question to say "process" rather than "class", since that seems to be what you're referring to and C does not have classes.

Comment: Once you successfully use one of the `exec`-family functions, the process image is replaced by that of what is being exec'd, so you cannot have the child process continually execing with the code in the program in question.  What you can do is continually fork and exec.

Comment: `while(1)` is an infinite loop. The child has already exited when you called `wait(0)`. So `waitpid()` returns immediately with an error, and the loop repeats.

Comment: @Kaylum I want my child's process to execute continuously with the parent process. So for example you can see that It works for the first input and output, But then with the 2nd there isn't any output as it's not interacting with the child anymore.

Comment: You need to put the loop around the code that does `fork` and `exec`.

Comment: You have to create a new child for each command you want to execute.

Comment: @barmar How would I go by doing this? Because I have already tried to use a while-loop with the exec within it, and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's comments I got it working.

---

Here's what I did.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(){


    while(1){

        char *cmd[] = {"pwd", "ls", "date", "ps", "top"};
        int i;
        printf("0=pwd, 1=ls, 2=date, 3=ps, 4=top:\n");
        printf("Please print your input: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);


        int The_fork = fork();  

        if(The_fork == 0){

            execlp(cmd[i], cmd[i], NULL);
            printf("command no found\n");
    
        }else{

            wait(0);
    
        }

        printf("\n");

    }



return 0;
}
```